# Refresh text in Applet

Tags: java, applet

I am doing this small race between two cars, in a java applet.
Just two pictures moving at random speed. I am calculating the distance between current position and the finish line, and you are suppose to be able to see the distance in the upper corner.

The thing is I am not able to refresh the text field, instead it just applies a new layer on top of the old number so it is almost impossible to read.
Here are pictures to demonstrate my problem.

I thought I would be able to solve it by creating the blue rectangle at the start of each loop but that does not seem to solve it.

[image: Initial]

[image: Image 2]

```
    public void action(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean race = true;
    int x1 =500, y1 = 233;
    int x2 = 500, y2 = 333;
    int speed1 = rand.nextInt(15) + -16;
    int speed2 = rand.nextInt(15) + -16;
    int finishline = 30;
    Text winnerBlue = new Text("Winner: BLUE",new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,20), Color.blue,Color.white);
    Text winnerRed = new Text("Winner: RED",new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,20), Color.red,Color.white);
    //background
    Text text =null;
    Text text2 = null;
    window.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 400, Color.GREEN);
    //track 1
    window.fillRect(20, 330, 550, 39, Color.gray);
    //track2
    window.fillRect(20, 230, 550, 39, Color.gray);

    //Finish line
    window.fillRect(40, 210, 10, 180, Color.BLACK);



    while(race){

        text = new Text(Integer.toString(x1),new Font("Courier",Font.BOLD,20), Color.WHITE);
        text2 = new Text(Integer.toString(x2),new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,20), Color.WHITE);
        window.fillRect(0, 0, 70, 50, Color.blue);
        window.fillRect(70, 0, 70, 50, Color.red);
        window.showImage(text, 0, 0);
        window.showImage(text2, 70, 0);

        window.showImage(car1.getImage(), x1, y1);
        window.showImage(car2.getImage(), x2, y2);

        car1.moveTo(x1 += speed1, y1);
        car2.moveTo(x2 += speed2, y2);
        window.pause(50);
        if(x1 <= (finishline ) ){
            speed1 = 0;
            speed2 = 0;
            window.showImage(winnerBlue, 200, 200);
            race = false;



            }
        if(x2 <= (finishline)){
            speed2 = 0;
            speed1 = 0;
            window.showImage(winnerRed, 200, 200);
            race = false;

        }

    }


}
```

}

Comment: It will depend on how you perform you painting and updates

Comment: Please show the relevant code.  Most likely what you're doing is creating a new frame on top of the old one rather than updating the text in your existing one

Comment: I just edited the post.

Comment: Are you using an `Applet` or a `JApplet`?

Comment: @KepaniHaole : Sorry this is actually a JFrame.

Comment: @MadProgrammer As was mentioned earlier it looks like Im always adding on a new layer and creating the object again and again instead of updating it. But I don't know how to update it.

Comment: Have you tried re-painting the image in the rectangle where your text is?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#repaint%28long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: @StormeHawke .. Where would I put that in the code?

Comment: Two things come to mind, 1- You seem to have a reference to the applets `Graphics` content in the form of `window`, this is not how custom painting should be performed 2- You may be blocking the Event Dispatching Thread.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: keeping in mind the above two comments, it would go after this:  `window.fillRect(0, 0, 70, 50, Color.blue);
        window.fillRect(70, 0, 70, 50, Color.red);`  But you should listen carefully to what @MadProgrammer had to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the two screen shots and supplied code snippt, it's clear that you don't understand how painting works in Swing/AWT.

Do NOT ever, maintain any kind of refernce to the `Graphics` context out side of the `paintXxx` methods.

The `paint` methods perform a number of very important steps to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting

Start by taking a look through [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)